# How to write conditional select insert statement to fetch record from a table, and based on some particular column's values

Tags: sql, oracle

for eg:

Table1:

```
c1,c2,c3 (1,10,'123')
```

Table2

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
```

Now I want to select record from table1 and if c3 column value starting two digit is 12 then I have to populate AA, and if 34 then BB in Table2 c4 column:

- Table1 -- (1,10,'123')
- Table2 -- (1,10,'123','AA')

---

- Table1 -- (1,10,'3444')
- Table2 -- (1,10,'3444','BB')

Comment: What if c3 does not start with 12 or with 34? Is c3 of type NUMBER or of type VARCHAR2 (or similar string data type)? If it's NUMBER, can the value in c3 be 12.99? and in that case you still want to insert 'AA'? Finally: what if such a row already exists in Table2? Say, you have (1, 10, 123) in Table1, but Table2 already has a row with the values (1, 10, 123, 'AA')? Or is table 2 currently empty, and you are starting to populate it?

Comment: you really need more examples.  For instance are the columns varchar2? number?  that information is needed to decide how to detect 12 or 34.  once that is known the problem becomes trivial.   take a good look at mathguys comment.   for sure I would add bad data to the mix.

Comment: i would also suggest providing the ddl to create the tables, and insert test data, so we all have the same data set to play with.

Comment: @mathguy  , thank for you time.
1)c3 is of type VARCHAR2

Comment: @mathguy  ,@EvilTeach   thanks for you time.
1)for c3 its fixed that no will start with either 12 or 34.
2)c3 is of type VARCHAR2
3)we will not get decimal no for input, only integers
4)duplicate values are allowed , so even if the table2 already  has same record, still we will insert into it.

 Hope i clarified your doubts. I am a beginner in SQL, not much idea how to put conditions on particular column for select insert query.
Waiting for ur reply..

Answer (score 0):

OP has provided additional information in Comments under the original post. In particular, `c3` is `VARCHAR2` and always begins with either `12` or `34`.

The following should work. If `c3` does not begin with `12` or `34`, then the value inserted in column `c4` will be `NULL`. That is the default behavior of `CASE` expressions, so it doesn't need to be coded explicitly; if instead something like `'ZZ'` is desired in that case, then we can add an `else` clause to `CASE`. (The OP said `c3` always begins with either `12` or `34`; if so, this is a moot point.)

```
insert into table2 ( c1, c2, c3, c4 )
  select c1, c2, c3,
         case when c3 like '12%' then 'AA'
              when c3 like '34%' then 'BB'
         end
  from   table1
;
```

**Demo**:

```
SQL> create table table1 ( c1 number, c2 number, c3 varchar2(25) );
Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 ( c1, c2, c3 ) values ( 1, 10, '123' );
1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 ( c1, c2, c3 ) values ( 1, 10, '3444' );
1 row created.

SQL> commit;
Commit complete.

SQL> select * from table1;

        C1         C2 C3
---------- ---------- -------------------------
         1         10 123
         1         10 3444

2 rows selected.
```

Then:

```
SQL> create table table2 ( c1 number, c2 number, c3 varchar2(25), c4 varchar2(10) );
Table created.

SQL> select * from table2;
no rows selected

SQL> insert into table2 ( c1, c2, c3, c4 )
  2    select c1, c2, c3,
  3           case when c3 like '12%' then 'AA'
  4                when c3 like '34%' then 'BB'
  5           end
  6    from   table1
  7  ;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from table2;

        C1         C2 C3                        C4
---------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
         1         10 123                       AA
         1         10 3444                      BB

2 rows selected.
```